# Chrome extension: make request and modify the page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How does one make a chrome extension that both:

1. Modifies the page
2. Makes a request to a server

I have tried every combination of adding to the "permissions" directory, but it does not seem to want to let me make a request to a server and modify the page in the same extension.

I have trouble understanding how this can be banned when other extensions (like grammarly) clearly must be doing both.

An acceptable answer is what permissions, or a link to an example app, or anything.

Comment: To modify the page use the *content script*. To make the request use the *background script* (service worker). To transfer the result use messaging, [example](/a/55292071).